# pyspark daterange calculations in spark

Tags: rdd, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to process website login session data by each user. I am reading an S3 session log file into an RDD. The data looks something like this.

```
----------------------------------------
User | Site   | Session start   | Session end
---------------------------------------
Joe  |Waterloo| 9/21/19 3:04 AM |9/21/19 3:18 AM

Stacy|Kirkwood| 8/4/19 3:06 PM  |8/4/19 3:54 PM

John |Waterloo| 9/21/19 8:48 AM |9/21/19 9:05 AM

Stacy|Kirkwood| 8/4/19 4:16 PM  |8/4/19 5:41 PM
...
...
```

I want to find out how many users were logged in each second of the hour on a given day.

Example: I might be processing this data for `9/21/19` only. So, I would need to remove all other records and then SUM user sessions for each second of the hour for all 24 hours of 9/21/19. The output should be possibly 24 rows for all the hours of 9/21/19 and then counts for each second of the day(yikes, second by second data!).

Is this something possible to do in pyspark using either rdds or DF?
(Apologize for the tardiness in building the grid).
Thanks

Comment: Well, it sounds you want to count how many users login for each hours of one day, and how many seconds they are login for those each hours. That is right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Using pyspark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## my dataset

```
data=[['Joe','Waterloo','9/21/19 3:04 AM','9/21/19 3:18 AM'],['Stacy','Kirkwood','8/4/19 3:06 PM','8/4/19 3:54 PM'],['John','Waterloo','9/21/19 8:48 AM','9/21/19 9:05 AM'],
          ['Stacy','Kirkwood','9/21/19 4:06 PM', '9/21/19 4:54 PM'],
         ['Mo','Hashmi','9/21/19 1:06 PM', '9/21/19 5:54 PM'],
         ['Murti','Hash','9/21/19 1:00 PM', '9/21/19 3:00 PM'],
         ['Floo','Shmi','9/21/19 9:10 PM', '9/21/19 11:54 PM']]
    cSchema = StructType([StructField("User", StringType())\
                          ,StructField("Site", StringType())
                          , StructField("Sesh-Start", StringType())
                          , StructField("Sesh-End", StringType())])
    df= spark.createDataFrame(data,schema=cSchema)
    display(df)
```

## parse timestamp

```
df1=df.withColumn("Start", F.from_unixtime(F.unix_timestamp("Sesh-Start",'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa'),'20yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').cast("timestamp")).withColumn("End", F.from_unixtime(F.unix_timestamp("Sesh-End",'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa'),'20yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').cast("timestamp")).drop("Sesh-Start","Sesh-End")
```

## build and register udf, for multiple hours per person

```
def yo(a,b):

  from datetime import datetime
  d1 = datetime.strptime(str(a), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  d2 = datetime.strptime(str(b), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  y=[]
  if d1.hour == d2.hour:
     y.append(d1.hour)
  else:
     for i in range(d1.hour,d2.hour+1):
        y.append(i)

  return y

rng= udf(yo, ArrayType(IntegerType()))
```

## explode list of hours into column

```
df2=df1.withColumn("new", rng(F.col("Start"),F.col("End"))).withColumn("new1",F.explode("new")).drop("new")
```

## get seconds for each hour

```
df3=df2.withColumn("Seconds", when(F.hour("Start")==F.hour("End"), F.col("End").cast('long') - F.col("Start").cast('long'))
               .when(F.hour("Start")==F.col("new1"), 3600-F.minute("Start")*60)
               .when(F.hour("End")==F.col("new1"), F.minute("End")*60)
               .otherwise(3600))
```

## create temp view and query it

```
df3.createOrReplaceTempView("final")
display(spark.sql("Select new1, sum(Seconds) from final group by new1 order by new1"))
```

## The above answer by Lennart could be more perfomant because he uses a join to get all the different hours, instead I use a UDF which could be slower. My code will work for any user who can be online for any amount of hours. My data used only the day required, so you could use day filter given above to limit your query to the day in question.. [Final output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4uxs.png)

Comment: Thanks. Very clear. I think the team here is getting greedy and wants to see if we can  to second by second per hour on number of users logged in. I will post a separate question for that.

Comment: That sounds like fun, ill keep an eye out for that question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this:

Initiaize filter.

```
val filter = to_date("2019-09-21")
val startFilter = to_timestamp("2019-09-21 00:00:00.000")
val endFilter = to_timestamp("2019-09-21 23:59:59.999")
```

Generate range (0 .. 23).

```
hours = spark.range(24).collect()
```

Get actual user sessions that match the filter.

```
df = sessions.alias("s") \
    .where(filter >= to_date(s.start) & filter <= to_date(s.end)) \
    .select(s.user, \
            when(s.start < startFilter, startFilter).otherwise(s.start).alias("start"), \
            when(s.end > endFilter, endFilter).otherwise(s.end).alias("end"))
```

Combine match user sessions with range of hours.

```
df2 = df.join(hours, hours.id.between(hour(df.start), hour(df.end)), 'inner') \
    .select(df.user, hours.id.alias("hour"), \
        (when(hour(df.end) > hours.id, 360).otherwise(minute(df.end) * 60 + second(df.end)) - \
         when(hour(df.start) < hours.id, 0).otherwise(minute(df.start) * 60 + second(df.start))).alias("seconds"))
```

Generate summary: calculate users count and sum of seconds for each hour of sessions.

```
df2.groupBy(df2.hour)\
    .agg(count(df2.user).alias("user counts"), \
         sum(dg2.seconds).alias("seconds")) \
    .show()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I am not as familiar with DataFrames and use RDDs for small projects. But this is a good start for me. I will load my data set in 'sessions' DF and name the columns 'start' and 'end' and take it from there.

Comment: You are welcome. You can check pyspark.sql.dataframe: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html and pyspark.sql.functions: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html.

Comment: I am getting an error "name 's' is not defined" while assigning an alias to DF in pyspark. Code is: df = interim_segmentsDF.alias("s"). \                                                                                                                                                                                                         where(filter_date >= datetime.strptime(s.recog_start, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) & (filter_date <= datetime.strptime(s.recog_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) . And it complains on the WHERE line.

Comment: That sounds syntax error... you can try to change to this format: df = interim_segmentsDF.alias("s")\ .where(....) note: .where clause is on new line.

Comment: Tried that already and didn't work. Do I need to perform from pypsark.sql.functions import *? If I do that it conflicts with some of my python functions I use like 'abs'.

Comment: You can use alias to include pyspark.sql.functions: from pyspark.sql.functions as f. So you can use ie: f.when(...).otherwise(...), etc. Hope this helps.